# MariaDB throws error with documented 'alter user' ... 'password expire' option

Tags: mariadb, percona-tools

Normally I use mysql-community on RHEL7, but today I installed MariaDB 10.3.20 on Ubuntu 19. In selectively cloning a database from the RHEL-mysql cluster to the Ubuntu-MariaDB cluster, I used Percona's `pt-show-grants` tool. It created for me lines such as:

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'xyz'@'%';
ALTER USER 'xyz'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' AS '*157C19AA12C99769CC33EEB0B46XF5A29C000000' REQUIRE NONE PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xyz`.* TO 'zzzz'@'%';
```

It fails on both `password expire` and `account unlock`. Only by removing both these mariadb not fail with:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER ACCOUNT UNLOCK' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, as noted, I am using 10.3.20, and these options are not support until the 10.4 series. I had assumed Ubuntu 19 was rather up-to-date. I also assumed percona's output would be more universal. Oh well.